# Cannot locate rosdep definition for [nodelet]

Tags: rosdep, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to install RGB-DSLAM to my machine following the instruction specified under "RGB-D SLAM for "Not-yet" ROS Users" and I encountered a bug.

when I typed this in the terminal:
$rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg

it returns:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [nodelet]

Some Specification: Ubuntu 12.10, 32-bit, Groovy, Opencv 2.4.5

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66391/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Bnodelet%5D/) by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like rosdep does not know that it is expecting groovy so cannot resolve nodelet to ros-groovy-nodelet.  Does the tutorial declare that it's using groovy?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what's in that tutorial..

Have you called `rosdep update` before? Does `rosdep db` print you anything?

Gonna put that line on the [rosdep wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdep).

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2